# Increase the version of npm in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a YAML pipeline on Azure DevOps for building our client-side scripts via npm.
The problem is that the pipeline is using version '6.14.13'. I would like to use a newer version that I am using locally, in this case, '7.19.1'. I ran `npm install npm@latest -g` at the start of the pipeline. However, it did not help as the next call to `npm --version` or when running e.g. `npm i` the pipeline's output to the console is displaying the old version '6.14.13'.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Run `npm install npm@latest -g` will only update the system npm.

The Npm@1 task shipping with Azure DevOps is using an npm installation at a custom location i.e. `/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/12.22.12/x64/bin/npm`. To update the Azure DevOps's npm, using the Npm@1's custom command like below,

```
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: custom
    customCommand: 'install -g npm@latest'
  displayName: 'Upgrade npm to latest version'
```

Comment: Could you explain some of your code, to make it easier to understand for future readers?

Answer (score -1):

We can use command the following command  to update the package.json version.

```
npm version <newversion>
```

For example, current version is v1.0.1, using command npm version 2.0.0 will update its version to v2.0.0.

Please note that the version format must be the same, like major.minor.patch.

Comment: this answer is totally off-topic.